# HTML5/CSS Vertical Nav height proportional to content

Tags: javascript, css, html, nav

```
        #wrapper{
        width: 960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border: 2px solid black;
        }

        #header{
        background-color:#2C394F;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        }

        #nav{

        line-height: 30px;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        height: #content;
        width: 150px;
        }

        #content{
        float: center;
        padding: 10px;

        }

        #footer{
        background-color: #2C394F;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body id="wrapper">


<div id="header">

        <h1>Title</h1>

</div>

<div id="nav">
    <a href="/page1.html">title</a><br>
    <a href="/page2.html"></a><br>
    <a href="/page3.html"></a><br>
    <a href="/page4.html"></a><br>
    <a href="/page5.html"></a><br>
</div>


<div id="content">

    <h3></h3>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>


    <h3></h3>

    <h3></h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>           
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <h3></h3>   

        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

    <h3></h3>

        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>       
        </ul>

</div>


<div id="footer">

    <p>&copy; 2015 </p>

</div>
```

Is there any way to get the nav height to automatically determine how long it needs to be according to the height of the content? I'll eventually put the internal css into an external css file for other pages later on with different content heights. I only need the nav to be proportional to the content and to end before the footer.

Comment: Is `#content` inside `#nav` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with the [table display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
        #wrapper{
        width: 960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border: 2px solid black;
        }

        #header{
        background-color:#2C394F;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        }

        #nav{

        line-height: 30px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100px;
          background-color: #eed;
          margin:5px
        }

        #content{
/*        float: center; that does not exists!!*/
        padding: 10px;
          

        }

        #footer{
        background-color: #2C394F;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        }

#container{
  display:table    
}

#nav,#content{
  display:table-cell;
   height:100%
}
```

```html
<body id="wrapper">


<div id="header">

        <h1>Title</h1>

</div>
<div id="container"> 
  
<div id="nav">
    <a href="/page1.html">title</a><br>
    <a href="/page2.html">title</a><br>
    <a href="/page3.html">title</a><br>
    <a href="/page4.html">title</a><br>
    <a href="/page5.html">title</a><br>
</div>


<div id="content">
The content
    <h3></h3>
        <ul>
            <li>li</li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>


    <h3></h3>

    <h3></h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>           
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <h3></h3>   

        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

    <h3></h3>

        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li>li</li>
            <li></li>
            <li>li</li>       
        </ul>

</div>


</div>
<div id="footer">

    <p>&copy; 2015 </p>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content should automatically determine the height of its container Element. Your padding and margins will not be considered part of the content when you are floating it. The best way to preserve content height when floating is to add another block level Element after the floating Element *(inside the parent of both of them)* and `clear:left;` on it.

```
.clearLeft{
  clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods for equal heights columns, one of my favorite is using one-true layout trick:

```css
.wrapper{
        width: 960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border: 2px solid black;
}

.header{
        background-color:#2C394F;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        background: DeepSkyBlue;
}

.nav{

        line-height: 30px;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-bottom: -9999px;
        padding-bottom: 9999px;
        background: MediumSeaGreen;
}

.container{
        overflow: hidden; 
}

.content{
        padding: 10px;
        background: Orchid;
        height: 500px; /* only for a sample */
}

.footer{
        background-color: #2C394F;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">Nav</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Also, **there is no** such float value as 'center'.